# Cannot assign element std::array directly, it says no operator "=" matches

Tags: c++, arrays

In my `processor` class there is an array `<Job, 10>`.

```
void Processor::addJob(Job job) {
    this->Jobs[this->uBound] = job;
    this->uBound++;
}
```

I'd like to add a new element inside my `processor` class. to do that i create new `private: int uBound = 0` property in my `processor` class. and I assign directly `this->Jobs[this->uBound] = job;`. it gives me an error. it says `Error : no operator "=" matches these operands. operand types are: std::array<Job, 10U> = Job`.

so I tried to use `this->Job->assign(Job)`; it assigned to all elements of my `Jobs`, but I just wanted only one element.

here the class of `Job`

```
class Job {
public:
    string name;

public :
    int length = 0;

public:
    bool used = false;

public:
    Job();

public:
    Job(string n, int l);


    ~Job();
};
```

and here the `Processor` class

```
class Processor {

private:
    int turnArround_time = 0;

private:
    int uBound = 0;

public:
    std::array<Job, 10> *Jobs = new std::array<Job, 10>();

public:
    Processor();

public:
    void addJob(Job job);

public:
    int getTurnArround();




    ~Processor();
};
```

I have no idea what does the error mean.

Is there any alternative way to add `Job` object to `Processor->Jobs` ?
any help appreciated, thanks...

Comment: You are trying to implement a dynamically-growing array. That's what `std::vector` is for.

Comment: The error means you have to declare an assignment operator for the type in question: `Job& operator=(const Job& rhs);`

Comment: You need to overload the `=` operator in your `Job` class. Have a look at this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: @TartanLlama so I use `const Job& rhs` to assign the `Jobs`??

Comment: okay, but I just want usign array instead. :) @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: @Jodivanz You'll need this operator such you can use the array in the way you want. I don't get what your comment means.

Comment: BTW, you probably don't need to dynamically allocate the `Jobs` array. It should work fine as just a regular class instance

Comment: @Levi Agree, and I suspect that's the root of it. You'd have to use something like `(*this->Jobs)[this->uBound] = job;`

Comment: Moral of the story: don't use dynamic allocation unless you REALLY have to. You'll get RSI from typing all those extra characters

Comment: Oh, about that, every `processor` may have more than one `Job`.... @Levi

@Component10, oh yeah it works, thanks...

Comment: hahaha, okay okay...

all I want now is finish the project, I'll figure out to prevent it later, just I have reported this project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct syntax will look like

( *this->Jobs )[this->uBound] = job;

Though it is not clear why the array is allocated dynamically.

Of course you also could write for example :)

```
this->Jobs[0][this->uBound] = job;
```

but it only confuses the reader of the code.

Comment: Because only that way I can work in entire Project....

I'll figure out how to use other way

Thanks!

Comment: An alternative would also be: `this->Jobs->at(this->uBound) = job;` but this also checks for the array bounds.

Comment: @erikzenker  Yes the operator can be called directly. I wanted to add this syntax but my answer was already marked as the best.:)